# Возможно ли копировать файл из удалённого каталога с помощью File.createTempFile("fileName", null)?

Tags: java, файлы, копирование

Я подключаюсь к `SFTP` используя `net.schmizz.sshj.sftp.SFTPClient`, получаю список файлов в нужном каталоге и могу копировать файл используя `getFileTransfer().download(distPath, localPath)`. Он позволяет копировать файл из удаленного каталога в локальный каталог.

Мне же нужно копировать файл из удаленного каталога во временный файл, созданный тут же в коде используя `File.createTempFile("fileName", null)`. Получится ли как то это сделать или стоит использовать другие библиотеки?

Comment: Используйте `open` вместо `download` https://javadoc.io/static/com.hierynomus/sshj/0.23.0/net/schmizz/sshj/sftp/SFTPClient.html#open-java.lang.String- и выкачивайте read-ом, результат складывайте в временный файл (если хотите через открытые файлы работать)

Comment: Шаг 1. f1=createTempFile на чтение-запись,  f2 = ftp.open ,  Шаг2 f2.read  f1.write пока всё не вычитаете. Шаг 3. f1.seek перемешаем указатель вначало.  f2.сlose(). Готово.